# display tables that has only less than 4 columns without group by

Tags: sql, sql-server

Display all tables that has less than 4 columns from all_tab_columns where owner ='GYS'  and starts with 'COL' without using group by function.

I am getting an error when tried with count/max functions . Any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: _Without using group by function_ implies that you _cannot_ use `COUNT()/MAX()` since those are aggregate functions requiring `GROUP BY`

Comment: This is the idea I had in mind : Select table_name, count(column_name) col from all_tab_columns where owner ='GYS' and table_name like 'COL%' having table_name.column_name <5 ;

Comment: Error Message: ORA-00904: "TABLE_NAME"."COLUMN_NAME": invalid identifier

Answer (score 1):

This Query will give you the Names of all the tables in you database where number of column are less then 4

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, COUNT(Column_Name) NumOfCols
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
GROUP BY TABLE_NAME
HAVING COUNT(Column_Name) < 4
```

Comment: Thank you for answering , I apologize for the delayed change!

Comment: Not a problem pal if this answer helped you accept the answer please :)

Answer (score 0):

```
declare
       cursor c1 
       is 
        select t.table_name, t.column_name, t.owner, 
       (select count('table_name.column_name') 
       from all_tab_columns ct where ct.table_name = t.table_name ) 
       as namecounter 
       from all_tab_columns t where t.owner ='GYS' and t.table_name like 'COL%';

       b1 c1%rowtype;
       tab_count number(10);
       temp_column varchar2(100);
begin
    open c1;
      loop
            fetch c1 into b1;

                  temp_column := b1.namecounter;
                  while temp_column <4 
                  loop
                  dbms_output.put_line(b1.table_name||b1.column_name||b1.namecounter);
                  tab_count:=c1%rowcount;
                  dbms_output.put_line(tab_count);
                  end loop;
       end loop;   
   close c1;
end;
/
```

I finally solved the above however in terms of execution speed it is running very slow, any ideas to improve performance would be appreciated!

Comment: use a query with GROUP BY?